# Download a PDF file via REST service with “Content-Disposition” Header in java

Tags: java, rest, pdf

I am trying to download a PDF file from a response of Java REST call after custom authentication check.

I can see downloaded file but it is empty file.

Below is my code snippet.

```
//Custom HTTPClient
HTTPAuthClient client = new HTTPAuthClient(url,username,password)
Request request = new Request(downloadURL); //I'm downloading file content of an URL.
Response response = client.executeGet(request);
String response1 = response.getResponseBody();
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getBytes());
response.setContentType("Content-type",application/pdf); //here response is      //javax.servlet.HttpServletResponse
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename="myfile.pdf");
IOUtils.copy(is,response.getOutPutStream());
response.flushBuffer();
```

With this code I could download the file but when I open the file and verified there is no data.
As  part of response body also I can see some data.

Could you please help me out where I'm doing mistake I tried many options but did not find solution.

Answer (score 1):

How can you use setContentType like this

```
response.setContentType("Content-type",application/pdf);
```

If only one avalible param in this method is String `void setContentType(String type)` so your method should be:

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
```

[Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html) to be sure.