# How to create a server url for local file to provide download on the frontend?

Tags: javascript, java, rest

I have a local file on the disk, so my purpose is to make a url for that file on local server(like https://localhost:8080/xxx), whatever make the url on backend and frontend. And then I can provide download with that url.  
I was trying to do that on the frontend, but since javascript cannot access to the local file system, I guess I might only can do it on backend? 

Or is there anyway I can directly post the local file as byte[] from backend to frontend with REST API? I tried to use Response to contain the file on backend, but I might did it wrong somehow it cannot be received on frontend.

Please give me some advices to achieve that, alternative solutions would be awesome, I would like to learn more. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic way to do that. You can use any URL you want. In your service you can decide, what URL you want to resolve to what file.

If you already do that, then check following:

1. Check if you set correct content type
2. Check if you really send ally the bytes of the file
3. If you expect that browser doesn't open the file in place but opens a save file dialog, check if you set header "Content-Disposition". See also hints [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574992/download-a-pdf-file-via-rest-service-with-content-disposition-header-in-java).